# What strategies can I use to update the visuals of my game to be more modern?

Tags: browser-based-games, php, graphics-design, html, css

I'm  making a browser strategy game.

Now my problem is that I have a feeling that my design is dated.
For now I have only used background colors and borders to make things look nice, but I have planed to add some pictures later.

Here is what it looks like now:

[[image]
*<sub>(Click for larger)</sub>*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5RoM.png)

You will see that the game has a top and bottom bar and has the main section in the middle.  My main concern is that this may not be best idea, because not full width and height of the window is used.

What strategies can I use to update the visuals of the site to a more modern look?

Comment: The game is not playable yet, you can't build building or send messages. You can only view the game. Only difference you can make is that new players are added to the rank list (refreshes every 30 min) and I can do that myself. Besides, you will get much better look at the game when you see it yourself then on a photo.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an actual question. If you can be specific about an actual issue (not something as general as how to make the game look better) you might get some better help.

Comment: You forgot: "Tell people what you've tried, why you don't think it works and how you want it to work."

Comment: @Byte56♦ The picture is what I tried. I don't think it works because I asked this on a forum and 1 guy said it looks old, and I know it is because I used a design from another game. And I don't know how do I want it to look, that is the point of the question.

Comment: I edited the question a bit more. I still think it's fairly broad as far as what can be done. However, I've reopened the question.

Comment: I think this is a fair question. The easiest answer is "look at modern browser games and copy one of those, instead."

Comment: Get an experienced UI designer/artist.  Or if you can't, do what ashes999 said.

Comment: Get a designer? I am doing this for practice, getting a designer to do it would be counter productive. Is there a browser game you played that you could suggest I check out?

Comment: @zor Design it yourself then? For me, design is about removing everything unnecessary. Suggestions are subjective though. There's also a [UX SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/), by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the important content take as much space as possible. Show utility buttons (like add/remove) only when needed. Replace the wall of text with images where possible. Where not, keep the text short. Take example from the design of good browser-based games.

If you are having a hard type designing the page take a look at those UI libraries that can make your life easier:

[JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/)

[Metro UI](http://metroui.org.ua/)

[Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/)

If those don't fit your design, use your favourite search engine to find more such libraries.